# Consider $I_n=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin(x)}dx$ , Show that $I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> > Question: Consider $I_n=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin(x)}dx$ , where $n \geq 0$
> >
> > Show that $I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$

What I have done:

$$I_n - I_{n-1}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin(2nx)}{\sin(x)}-\frac{\sin(2(n-1)x)}{\sin(x)} dx$$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin(2nx)-\sin(2(n-1)x)}{\sin(x)} dx$$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{\sin(x)} \left(\sin(2nx)-\sin(2(n-1)x)\right) dx$$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{\sin(x)} \left(2\cos\left(\frac{2nx+2nx-2x}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{2x}{2}\right)\right) dx$$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{1}{\sin(x)} \left(2\cos\left((2n-1)x\right) \sin\left(x\right)\right) dx$$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=2 \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos((2n-1)x) dx $$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=2 \left[\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1} \right]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 $$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2}{2n-1} \left[\sin((2n-1)x)\right]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 $$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2}{2n-1} \left[\sin((2n-1)x)\right]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 $$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2}{2n-1} \left[(-1) \cdot \cos(n\pi) \right] $$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2}{2n-1} \left[ (-1) \cdot (-1)^{n+1} \right]$$

$$ I_n - I_{n-1}=\frac{2(-1)^{n+2}}{2n-1} $$

Which is not what they were looking for.

Comment: $\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$, $\enspace$ *n o t*  $\enspace\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^{n+1}$ :-)

Comment: @user90369 But even then I do not get the answer that they require?

Comment: Use $(-1)^{n-1}$ instead of $(-1)^{n+1}$, it's the same. It's a taste thing what you like to use here.